# Base of the $\mathbb{R}$ vector space that contains all real functions: $f(x) \not= 0$ for finitely many x $\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I did already prove that this is a vector space. It is easily shown that addition and scalar multiplication with functions that hold the above property again yields a function with $f(x) \not= 0$ for finitely many x $\in\mathbb{R}$.

How can i find the base of this vector space? How can i find function(s) in a way that they constitute a generating system for all functions that are

\begin{cases}
\not= 0 & \text{for a "finite" condition}\\
 0& \text{in any other case}\\
\end{cases}

and prove my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider, as an example, the function $f(x)$ defined by:

$$\begin{array}{lll}
f(1)=3\\
f(2)=-\pi\\
f(x)=0,\mbox{ for all other } x\\
\end{array}$$

Now define functions $f_i(x)$ so that $f_i(x)=1$ if $x=i$ and $f_i(x)=0$ if $x\neq i$. Can you write $f$ as a linear combination of $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
f_y(x)=\begin{cases}0\text{ if }x\neq y\\1\text{ if }x=y\end{cases}.
$$
Further, let 
$$
B=\{f_y(x):y\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$
Try to see if you can show $B$ is a basis for this space.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: What is the simplest example of a non-zero vector you can think of? What are its scalar multiples? Obviously in a base you don't need all scalar multiples, so just pick **one** (I repeat, **1**) of those. Repeat for all those "simplest examples of non-zero vectors". Voila (prove that you now have) a base.